jmeter response body - requested URL is not allowed
I am sending request on like this similar url
"https://prod-imageproxy.xyz.co.uk/182,fit/https://xyz-images-ssl.cdn.xyz.com/5/8/1023455/l_1024585.jpg"
in jmeter but getting response body as "requested URL is not allowed" and response headers are 403 forbidden,
(there is image proxy url added from in front of other image url)
same request I am able to use in browser and postman and its working in both as expected,
I tried to add sampler manually also tried using recorder  but all have same failed response,
also tried some other option on/off like redirect automatically and follow redirects but nothing worked for me
can someone guide me please ?

I'll highly encourage you to post screenshots of entire screen of JMeter.
Have you set Cookies manager and HTTP header in your thread group ??   Those are tiny to miss but are very notorious to find. Also, set the Content-Type and Accept header values to correct MIME-Type, and make sure they are on the top inside the thread group.

Thank you, I will try and  check with your suggestions

I don't think that https://prod-imageproxy.xyz.co.uk/182,fit/https://xyz-images-ssl.cdn.xyz.com/5/8/1023455/l_1024585.jpg is a valid URL, as it doesn't correspond to the specification
If you're able to run the request in Postman or browser you can just record it using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. JMeter documentation on the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder for browser is quite comprehensive, for Postman you can refer How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling article, the key points are:

Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy


Import JMeter's certificate into Postman




Thank you, I will try and check with your suggestions
